# Latex includes a png file ./....png that I cannot find on my computer

Tags: graphics, pdftex, png, files

I have a working latex code for a paper. It uses one image graphics file named ./DecompMatrFoValpha..png as I see in my log file on p. [4]. All other image files on later pages [5],[6] are findable ... and
sit in the same folder where the tex file resides and they appear in the log file without the ./ in front.

I cannot find that ./...png file anywhere in the folder or on the computer anywhere.

Where could it be, how did it get the ./ designation?

I need to provide this file  to the Journal, so that they can make the galleys, but where is the file?
Here is part of the log file:

========================================

<DecompMatrFoValpha.png, id=71, 910.40125pt x 777.90625pt>
File: DecompMatrFoValpha.png Graphic file (type png)

Package pdftex.def Info: DecompMatrFoValpha.png used on input line 119.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 369.88582pt x 316.05923pt.
 [3]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 129--133

[]

[4 <./DecompMatrFoValpha.png>]
<allblFovs250_30blks.png, id=95, 1150.2975pt x 997.7275pt>
File: allblFovs250_30blks.png Graphic file (type png)

Package pdftex.def Info: allblFovs250_30blks.png used on input line 140.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 364.19527pt x 315.88435pt.
 [5]

File: diag01patt250_30blks.png Graphic file (type png)

Package pdftex.def Info: diag01patt250_30blks.png used on input line 146.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 261.76535pt x 268.11298pt.

<Fov250_30blks.png, id=102, 1046.91125pt x 1037.8775pt>
File: Fov250_30blks.png Graphic file (type png)
s

Comment: Did you get all these files from someone else originally?

Comment: Standard latex requires no image files.  Some journal templates (ieeeaccess for example) do.

Comment: You lost your image? Why don't you get it back from [arXive.org](https://arxiv.org/format/2006.01241)? Click on `Download source`, it's in the tar-ball...

Comment: The `./` in front of a filename is a relative path and mean the working directory, not the parent directory (`../`), nor the parent of the parent directory (`../../`), nor in some child directory (`whatever-else/`). The image must be where is the main document.

Comment: I created these graphic files from Matlab via screen grabs. 4 of these are ok and show up in the folder where the tex file etc resides. Two have ./name.png 'names' in the log file and they are nowhere to be found.

Comment: Of course, or sadly : when I want to move all those files into a subfolder for that one paper, then the tex file does not work from the subfolder since these ./... graphics cannot be found. Searching for them shows no results.

Comment: I eventually gave up on locating the 'missing files' and created a new similar example and its 3associated plots (2 of which originally were missing). That took me 1-2 hours and then all wa as before with slightly different graphs for another random entry example.

Comment: Of course I do not know how Latex could create my pdf file without any trace of the 2 images that were included in the old pdf file. I hope that never happens again, to me or others. But for now the problem has been solved the hard way, by sweat and tears ... Thanks!